# How sqoop2 import mysql to HBase

Tags: sqoop

I know Sqoop 1.4.* supports import to HBase no problems. But when I start using Sqoop2, here is what happened:

```
sqoop:000> create job --xid 1 --type import
Creating job for connection with id 1
Please fill following values to create new job object
Name: First job

Database configuration

Schema name: test
Table name: Student
Table SQL statement: select * from Student
Table column names: id,name
Partition column name: id
Boundary query:

Output configuration

Storage type:
  0 : HDFS
```

As you can see, the last prompt doesn't give me any other options but 0:HDFS? I am sure Sqoop2 job supports import to HBase? It's very hard to find any documents around Sqoop2. Can some one give me a pointer?

Comment: Did you get the answer for your question? Thanks.

Comment: @YongJiangZhang yes, I did, unfortunately Sqoop2 doesn't support it yet.